# Ripple carry adder using Half adder and 2 Full adder

Tags: vhdl

I'm creating a ripple carry adder using the following Diagram.

[image]

I have the following code writte, but when I run the simulation it's all over the place and I'm banging my head as to why this is happening. I'm very new to this whole thing and I admit, I do feel intimidated by these stuff.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity ripple_carry_adder is
  port (
    a_in  : in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    b_in  : in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    s_out : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    carry : out std_logic
    );
end ripple_carry_adder;


architecture gate of ripple_carry_adder is

  signal carry_0, carry_1, carry_2 : std_logic := '0';

begin
  --first half adder
  s_out(0)   <= a_in(0) xor b_in(0);
  carry_0 <= a_in(0) and b_in(0);

--second full adder
  s_out(1) <= a_in(1) xor b_in(1) xor carry_0;
  carry_1  <= (a_in(1) and b_in(1)) or (a_in(1) and carry_0) or (b_in(1) and carry_0);
--third full adder
  s_out(2) <= a_in(2) xor b_in(2) xor carry_1;
  carry_2  <= (a_in(2) and b_in(2)) or (a_in(2) and carry_1) or (b_in(2) and carry_1);
--final carry assignment
  carry    <= carry_2;

end gate;
```

and here is the test bench code, I've omitted some useless stuff from the beginning.

```
- The behavior is written inside architecture
architecture testbench of tb_ripple_carry_adder is
  -- First, there are definitions


  -- Define constants: bit widths and duration of clk period
  constant input_w_c    : integer := 3;
  constant output_w_c   : integer := 4;
  constant clk_period_c : time    := 100 ns;

  -- Component declaration of  Design Under Verification (DUV)
  component ripple_carry_adder
    port (
      a_in  : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      b_in  : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      s_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
  end component;

  -- Define the needed signals
  signal clk     : std_logic := '0';
  signal rst_n   : std_logic := '0';
  signal term1_r : unsigned(input_w_c-1 downto 0);
  signal term2_r : unsigned(input_w_c-1 downto 0);

  signal sum     : unsigned(output_w_c-1 downto 0);
  signal sum_slv : std_logic_vector(output_w_c-1 downto 0);

begin  -- testbench
  -- The actual behavior starts here


  -- Instantiate DUV and connect it to testbench's signals
  i_ripple_carry_adder : ripple_carry_adder
    port map (
      a_in  => std_logic_vector(term1_r),
      b_in  => std_logic_vector(term2_r),
      s_out => sum_slv);
  sum <= unsigned(sum_slv);


  -- Generate rst signals to initialize registers
  rst_n <= '1' after clk_period_c*2;

  -- purpose: Generate clock signal for DUV
  -- type   : combinational
  -- inputs : clk (this is a special case for test purposes!)
  -- outputs: clk
  clk_gen : process (clk)
  begin  -- process clk_gen
    clk <= not clk after clk_period_c/2;
  end process clk_gen;



  -- purpose: Generate all possible inputs values and check the result
  -- type   : sequential
  -- inputs : clk, rst_n
  -- outputs: term1_r, term2_r
  input_gen_output_check : process (clk, rst_n)
  begin  -- process input_gen_output_check
    if rst_n = '0' then                 -- asynchronous reset (active low)

      -- Reset all registers here
      term1_r <= (others => '0');
      term2_r <= (others => '0');

    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then  -- rising clock edge

      -- Increment term1 on every clock cycle (else-branch)
      -- Increment also term2 when term1 has max value (if-branch)
      -- Simulation terminates when term2 has max value
      if (to_integer(term1_r) = 2**input_w_c-1) then
        term1_r <= (others => '0');
        if (term2_r = 2**input_w_c-1) then
          assert false report "Simulation ended!" severity failure;
          -- "Failure" forces simulator to stop, so it is not dangerous in this
          -- case
        else
          term2_r <= to_unsigned(to_integer(term2_r) + 1, input_w_c);
        end if;
      else
        term1_r <= to_unsigned(to_integer(term1_r) + 1, input_w_c);
      end if;

      -- Check the result. This condition should always be true. If not, the report message will be printed.
      assert to_integer(sum) = to_integer(term1_r) + to_integer(term2_r)
        report "Output signal is not equal to the sum of the inputs"
        severity error;

    end if;
  end process input_gen_output_check;

end testbench;
```

I keep getting `"Output signal is not equal to the sum of the inputs"`
And here is the simulation wave.

[image]

Comment: There is not useless stuff in VHDL, your testbench is missing the entity declaration and it's context clause. The ripple_carry_adder output `carry` is not bound in the default binding indication. There's also an assertion warning from package numeric_std `NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0` continually through your simulation, where the red shows up on your waveform with the unreadable names (`sum` ->  `sum(3)` and `sum_slv` -> `sum_slv(3)`) and where [s_out(3) should be driven by `carry_2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmY9N.jpg), eliminating errors and warnings.

Comment: In other words, make the entity and architecture for ripple_carry_adder correspond to the schematic image.

Comment: Yeah I found the problem, I wasn't passing anything to the `s_out(3)`, so instead of ` carry    <= carry_2;` I did `s_out(3)  <= carry_2 ` and now evreything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I never assigned a value to `s_out(3)`. So I re-wrote my code to the following.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity ripple_carry_adder is
  port (
    a_in  : in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    b_in  : in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    s_out : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end ripple_carry_adder;


architecture gate of ripple_carry_adder is

  signal carry_ha, carry_fa, carry_final : std_logic := '0';

begin
  --first half adder
  s_out(0) <= a_in(0) xor b_in(0);
  carry_ha <= a_in(0) and b_in(0);

--second full adder
  s_out(1) <= a_in(1) xor b_in(1) xor carry_ha;
  carry_fa <= (a_in(1) and b_in(1)) or (a_in(1) and carry_ha) or (b_in(1) and carry_ha);

--third full adder
  s_out(2)    <= a_in(2) xor b_in(2) xor carry_fa;
  carry_final <= (a_in(2) and b_in(2)) or (a_in(2) and carry_fa) or (b_in(2) and carry_fa);

--final carry assignment
  s_out(3) <= carry_final;

end gate;
```